# Can't put normal encoded text into DB table: Hibernate 4.3.4 + mySQL 5.1.30

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I use Win7 + Spring + Hibernate + mySQL + JSP.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

JSP-view:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
....
<form:form acceptCharset="windows-1251">
```

Hib-config:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">cp1251</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">cp1251</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.dreamer.domain.Question"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my.ini:

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
init-connect="SET NAMES cp1251"
init-connect="SET CHARACTER SET cp1251"
character_set_server=cp1251
collation_server=cp1251_general_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

And "show variables ..." request result:
[image]

But after feeling view form and sending the data, I get only information in th next encoding:
������!
"������, ������!"

Pls, tell me, what is wrong?

Comment: Try <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB?characterEncoding=cp1251</property> instead <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB</property> or maybe better using UTF8.

Comment: not working = ( I've tried even "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=cp1251", and it also doesn't work = (

Comment: Why do you use cp1251 instead UTF-8 in your MySQL?

Comment: It's my own request! Я русский!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the filter in your web.xml

```
     <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
                    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                    <param-value>cp1251</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
                    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>



    <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html

Comment: Maybe this link be helpful for you too: http://skipy.ru/technics/encodings_webapp.html#server

Comment: Thank's so much dude! This article is realy works!!!! I should create my own filter-class!!!!! It's cool! Great! But tell me s, what encoding should I use? UTF-8 or CP1251?